# Retag Request: [windows-backup] -> [windows] & [backup]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

Can you retag superuser posts with the [windows-backup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-backup) tag with windows and backup tags?

- Windows - 435
- Backup - 39

I think this would make searching and using the interesting/ignored tags easier.

Comment: Definitely worth discussing.

Answer (score 4):

"Windows backup" seems to be a pretty specific term; I'm not sure there is a need to make it less specific?

Also - the tools don't allow us to split, so the 39 would have to be handled manually, **even if** this was desirable (I'm not convinced, personally; I think of "windows backup" as the MS tools; "backup" and/or "windows" could mean any product...)

Comment: Fair enough, I think most would agree.